# get data options from laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

HTML:

```
<label>place</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="provice" id="provice">
      <option value="0">test</option>
      @foreach ($provincees as $key => $value)
          <option value="{{ $value->id }}">{{ $value->name }}</option>                 
      @endforeach
</select>
```

I want to get the data name and insert to database, province name searched by using the id found in the select option.

I use this to get the name based on the select id :

```
$results = DB::select('select name from provincees where id = ?',$request->provice);
```

I have this code for insert datas :

```
 $i=DB::insert("INSERT
    INTO place
       (id,name)
    VALUES
       (?,?,?,?)
    ",[$request->provice,$results]);
```

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Hello @fadil. Please have a look on how Laravel deals with forms. Usually you need to configure a route for the form request, where you will call your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is usiing `query builder` ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#inserts

```php
  $results = DB::table('provincees')->select('name')->where('id',$request->provice)->first();
        $i = DB::table('provincees')->insert([
            'id'=>$request->provice,
            'name'=>$results->name,
        ]);
```